Is SignalR event listener correctly disposed after reload of page?
I have a page component where i add a SignalR HubConnection:
@page "/test"
@using System.Diagnostics
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client
@rendermode InteractiveServer

@implements IAsyncDisposable

<PageTitle>Test</PageTitle>

<button @onclick="SendMessage">Send Message</button>

@foreach(var m in _messages)
{
    <p>@m</p>
}

@code {
    private readonly List<string> _messages = [];
    private HubConnection? _hubConnection;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl("http://localhost:5200/message")
            .WithAutomaticReconnect()
            .Build();

        _hubConnection.On<string>("OnMessage", GetMessage);

        await _hubConnection.StartAsync();

        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

    private void GetMessage(string message)
    {
        _messages.Add(message);
        Debug.WriteLine(message);
        InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        if (_hubConnection is not null)
        {
            _hubConnection.Remove("OnMessage");
            await _hubConnection.StopAsync();
            await _hubConnection.DisposeAsync();
        }
    }

    private async Task SendMessage()
    {
        await _hubConnection.SendAsync("SendMessage", "Hello");
    }

}

With this code you can send a message by clicking a button and every connected client is receiving this message.
On the server i just forward the messages to all clients
public async Task SendMessage(string message)
{
    await Clients.All.SendAsync("OnMessage", message);
}

In my GetMessage function I write the message to the output window Debug.WriteLine(message);.
When I open the page and click my send button the message gets displayed once on my page and once in my output window.
But if I refresh the page and click again, the message gets displayed once on my page but twice in my output window as if the first event listener is still registered, although it should have been disposed, shouldn't it?
If you track the current circuit and put that in the output as well you can see that the GetMessage function gets called from both circuits (the one before and the one after the refresh) (I haven't put that in the code to keep it simple).
Is the event handler not being disposed correctly? how can it even work when the hubconnection is closed and disposed? what do I misunderstand here?
EDIT this is the output when trying @jalpa panchal's answer after a refresh of the page


You could try this code which will help you avoid multiple event handlers:
_Host.cshtml:
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@namespace BlazorSignalRProject.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="BlazorSignalRProject.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
</head>
<body>
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="Server" />

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        <environment include="Staging,Production">
            An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
        </environment>
        <environment include="Development">
            An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        </environment>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/microsoft-signalr/3.1.18/signalr.min.js"></script>
</body>

MessageHub.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace BlazorSignalRProject.Hubs
{
    public class MessageHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task SendMessage(string message)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("OnMessage", message);
        }
    }
}

Test.razor:
@page "/test"
@using System.Diagnostics
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@implements IAsyncDisposable

<PageTitle>Test</PageTitle>

<button @onclick="SendMessage">Send Message</button>

@foreach (var m in _messages)
{
    <p>@m</p>
}

@code {
    private readonly List<string> _messages = new List<string>();
    private HubConnection? _hubConnection;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (_hubConnection is null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("OnInitializedAsync - Initializing HubConnection");
            _hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl(NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/message"))
                .WithAutomaticReconnect()
                .Build();

            _hubConnection.On<string>("OnMessage", GetMessage);

            await _hubConnection.StartAsync();
            Debug.WriteLine("HubConnection Started");
        }

        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

    private void GetMessage(string message)
    {
        _messages.Add(message);
        Debug.WriteLine($"GetMessage - Received message: {message}");
        InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        if (_hubConnection is not null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("DisposeAsync - Disposing HubConnection");
            _hubConnection.Remove("OnMessage");
            await _hubConnection.StopAsync();
            await _hubConnection.DisposeAsync();
            Debug.WriteLine("DisposeAsync - HubConnection Disposed");
        }
    }

    private async Task SendMessage()
    {
        if (_hubConnection is not null)
        {
            await _hubConnection.SendAsync("SendMessage", "Hello");
            Debug.WriteLine("SendMessage - Message sent");
        }
    }
}

Program.cs:
using BlazorSignalRProject.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using BlazorSignalRProject.Hubs;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
//builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
builder.Services.AddSignalR();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<CircuitHandler, LoggingCircuitHandler>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapHub<MessageHub>("/message");
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();

public class LoggingCircuitHandler : CircuitHandler
{
    public override Task OnCircuitOpenedAsync(Circuit circuit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Circuit Opened: {circuit.Id}");
        return base.OnCircuitOpenedAsync(circuit, cancellationToken);
    }

    public override Task OnCircuitClosedAsync(Circuit circuit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Circuit Closed: {circuit.Id}");
        return base.OnCircuitClosedAsync(circuit, cancellationToken);
    }
}

try to clean and rebuild the project and test it also check the console and debug windows logs
Result:



thanks for your answer but it doesn't change the behavior

@Rich could you try updated code

I copied your updated code but after a refresh of the page I still get 2 received messages instead of 1. I edit my question with a screenshot of the output

@Rich try the updated code or just create new project and only use this code on that

I did create a new project and copied your code. Unfortunately the problem remains

@Rich could you share your complete code of yours. make sure there is no duplicate registrations. try to set   _initialized = true; to make sure initialization only happens once.
